# Linq several relations

Tags: linq

I can't make it works.... I've got 4 tables:

**T1** (1)---(N) **T2** (N)---(1) **T3** (1)--(N) **T4**

So, from T1 how can I get T4 data being T1 an IQueryable that I get from previous select?

I tried T1.T2.Where(x=>...Select(y=>..)) cause I think select is for this case because T3's relations but I doesn't compile...

I've got it working with no previous IQueryable statement, using inner joins, but because other things I need it to work that way.

Comment: Could you provide some code for these classes? You need to define navigation properties and then either load with Include (eager loading) or enable lazy loading if using EF 6

Comment: Every navigation property is already defined. No idea about include :S

Comment: Somthing like t1.t2.include('t3').include('t3.t4')..????

Comment: Without class definitions its hard to give you an answer. This page may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank u but I don't have here the code, is from my job... sorry. But with the relations I put up there u don't need any thing else to answer , don't you??? Thanks

Comment: You don't need to provide the full code, you need to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If I don't know what you classes and properties are I can't tell you what exactly the Include should look like. If T2 is a type name what is T1.T2? A single T2? An ICollection<T2>? Presumably there is a DbContext in there somewhere? What you have doesn't look like a Linq query and isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void getT4s()
{
    var t1 = new T1();
    var t4s = t1.T2s.Select(x => x.T3).SelectMany(x => x.T4s);
}


public class T1
{
    public ICollection<T2> T2s { get; set; }
}

public class T2
{
    public T3 T3 { get; set; }
}

 public class T3
{
    public ICollection<T2> T4s { get; set; }
}

public class T4
{

}
```

Comment: According to the question T1 is an IQueryable, this assumes its an in memory object.